# Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

There are a couple of other questions on here regarding this but they are old and have not been answered satisfactorily IMHO.

I am getting this error - "Unknown record property / related component 
"permissions" on "sfGuardUser", referer:" - in my error_log when I 
attempt to login to my symfony 1.4 app after deployment. I do not get 
it on my local machine.

When I submit the login form, Symfony throws a 500 error. If I refresh 
the page, the login form is reposted and I am logged in.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this?

Comment: N.B. I have tried clearing cache and doctrine:build --all-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/102097/

The solution is:

```
rm ./lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseSfGuard*
./symfony cc
```

from http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/102097/

It seems that at some point I had this relation defined in my own schema file and this had been cached somewhere. When I moved the code to a new server without the cache, Symfony generated classes in a location which overrode the plugin's versions.

Answer (score 0):

> When I submit the login form, Symfony
>   throws a 500 error. If I refresh the
>   page, the login form is reposted and I
>   am logged in.

What browser do you use? I have same problem,but only in Opera...

Comment: This should have been a comment as it isn't an answer. I dont use Opera. It happens in Firefox 3.6 & Safari on Mac. I haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: I can not add comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using build all commands. If an SQL statement fails, building all can delete data. Never user build all commands on a production environment for Symfony.