# Symfony 1.4 - will "doctrine:build-model" destroy the data in the database?

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfguard

I am a bit new to Symfony. I have encountered this issue:
[Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937325/unknown-record-property-related-component-permissions-on-sfguarduser)

Its solution mentioned there is deleting certain files in `lib/model/doctrine/base/`. However, I want to know if we are going to rebuild model, what will be the impact.

On this page you can see:
http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/102097/
someone mentioned that a permanent fix is to delete these files as well as fix the schema. And then we will build:model again.

So will this delete the data in the database? Whats the impact of `doctrine:build` command on symfony?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no,  doctrine:build-model won't drop any data in your database. It will only overwrite your base model classes in lib/model/base and create model files if they don't exist.

From the *sfDoctrineBuildTask* class, doctrine:build will "build" what you give in option. That means "doctrine:build --model" is the same as "doctrine:build-model". But I guess in many symfony 1.4 tutorials like Jobeet, they only use "doctrine:build --model"